# Using Eclipse JDT to find all identifiers visible within a specific node

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working on a plug-in to Eclipse JDT that parses Java files and offers automatic corrections to them. I'm doing so using Eclipse's API for analyzing the AST.

I'm trying to write a method that calculates the [environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)#Lexical_environment) of a method - a list of all the identifiers that are visible within the scope of the method. Another way to look at this is the list of identifiers that can be auto-completed from a specific point in Eclipse.

For example:

```
import ...

public class MyClass {
    private static final int a = 3;
    private boolean b;

    float someMethod(String s) {
        int c = 3;
        (X);    
    }
}
```

The environment in `(X)` is composed of the identifiers `a`, `b`, `c` and `s`.

How can I calculate the environment of a method in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some working code that **solves the given simple example**, but **needs to be extended** for more complex code:

- Scopes, e. g. `int a = 1; { int b = 2; } (X)` (environment: `a` only)
- Inheritance
- Static imports with or without wildcards, e. g. `import static java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE;` or `import static java.lang.Integer.*;`
- ...

The basic principle is to travel the AST and access cross connections via `node.resolveBinding()`.

```
public class Environment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String code = "public class MyClass {\n" +
                "    private static final int a = 3;\n" +
                "    private boolean b;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    float someMethod(String s) {\n" +
                "        int c = 3;\n" +
                "        // (X);\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";
        for (IBinding binding : of(code, code.indexOf("(X)"))) {
            System.out.println(binding.getName());
        }
    }

    public static List<IBinding> of(String code, int offset) {
        final List<IBinding> environment = new ArrayList<>();
        createAst(code).accept(new ASTVisitor(true) {

            public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
                if (offset < node.getStartPosition()) return false;
                environment.add(node.resolveBinding());
                return true;
            }

            public boolean visit(SingleVariableDeclaration node) {
                if (offset < node.getStartPosition()) return false;
                environment.add(node.resolveBinding());
                return true;
            }

        });
        return environment;
    }

    private static CompilationUnit createAst(String code) {

        // parser
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS10);
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);
        parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
        parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);

        // options
        final Hashtable<String, String> options = JavaCore.getOptions();
        options.put("org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source", "1.8");
        parser.setCompilerOptions(options);

        // sources and classpath
        String[] sources   = new String[] { /* source folders */ };
        String[] classpath = new String[] { /* JARs */};
        String[] encodings = new String[sources.length];
        Arrays.fill(encodings, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        parser.setEnvironment(classpath, sources, encodings, true);
        parser.setUnitName("code");
        parser.setSource(code.toCharArray());

        // abstract syntax tree
        return (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    }

}
```

Alternatively, the fields (including constants) can be collected at `visit(TypeDeclaration node)` via `node.getFields()` or the parameters of a method at `visit(MethodDeclaration node)` via `node.parameters()` earlier in the AST.

Comment: The definition scope/lifecycle of local vars is not considered, e.g., for another method like float beforeMethod(String s) { int e = 0; }, e will also be printed but apparently it is not accessible/live in {X}

Comment: @K.Symbol Yes, to consider scopes or only specific types or methods, in `createAst(code).accept(new ASTVisitor(true) { ... }` more `visit(...)` ASTVisitor methods have to be implemented to travel the abstract syntax tree. In this simple example all variables of `VariableDeclarationFragment` and `SingleVariableDeclaration` nodes will be listed and the entire abstract syntax tree will be visited since both `visit(...)` methods return `true`. The [AST View](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ast-view) might be helpful by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to obtain the `ICompilationUnit` from the class you want to parse.
Then you can make `visitors` for the node types you need, as `MethodDeclaration`.

```
public class MainMethodVisitor extends ASTVisitor {

    List<MethodDeclaration> methods = new ArrayList<MethodDeclaration>();

    @Override
    public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
     ... //do stuff with the node
```

And call it with:

```
ICompilationUnit unit;
//...
CompilationUnit parse = parse(unit);
MainMethodVisitor visitor = new MainMethodVisitor();
parse.accept(visitor);
```

Having the method node, you can access to its paramenters with `node.parameters()`  to obtain `s`. You'll have to find out what type of nodes are class's members variables (`a`, `b`).
Last thing to do is access to, i think, `VariableDeclaration` inside the method node in order to obtain `c`.

Thats all i have to help you. Hope it helps.