# Compile external Java file during runtime using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

Is it possible to dynamically compile an external .java file using the Java compiler that eclipse uses rather than JDK?

What I want my code to do is:

1. Dynamically create a .java file
2. Compile that .java file
3. Use reflection to get info about this file

I know how to do steps 1 and 3 but is step 2 possible just using Eclipse or are there better ways to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Java compiler for that. You do not need to compile the `.java` file, just parse it to get an abstract syntax tree (AST) containing the information.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Eclipse's batchCompiler found in org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch.BatchCompiler: https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Java compiler for that. You do not need to compile the `.java` file, just parse it to get an abstract syntax tree (AST) containing the information:

1. Add the [required Eclipse compiler JARs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50311348/6505250) as dependencies to your Java application
2. Create an AST and get the information you want, e.g. like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53304074/6505250)